# Access items in popupmenu for BarButtonItem, devXpress, winforms

Tags: c#, popupmenu, menuitem-selection

I am new to devxpress.
I use a BarManager, on witch I add BarButtonItems at runtime. The BarButtonItem has a PopupMenu witch contains BarButtonItems.

I need to populate a TreeList with the buttons hierarchy. I can access the buttons on the bar, but how to access the buttons on the popup for that button on bar?

To add buttons on bar I use:

```
bar2.LinksPersistInfo.Add(new LinkPersistInfo(toolStripMenuItem));
```

To add buttons on popup I use:

```
popupSubMenu.ItemLinks.Add(toolStripSubMenuItem);
```

To add popoup to button I use:

```
toolStripMenuItem.ActAsDropDown = true;
toolStripMenuItem.ButtonStyle = BarButtonStyle.DropDown;
toolStripMenuItem.DropDownControl = popupSubMenu;
```